# stream with Merge statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

> Hi  Below are the steps I followed to implement merge with stream in
> snowflake
> 1.created a table
> **create or replace table employees(employee_id number,
> salary number,
> manager_id number);**
> 2. Created stream.
> **create or replace stream employees_stream on table employees;**
> 3. created consumer table.
> **create or replace table employees_consumer(employee_id number,
> salary number,manager_id number);**
> 4. I inserted some records in employees table.  **insert into employees values(8,40000,4),
> (12,50000,9),
> (3,30000,5),
> (4,10000,5),
> (25,35000,9);**
> 5.While trying to execute below command I am getting error.
> **MERGE INTO EMPLOYEES_CONSUMER AS A USING (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES_STREAM WHERE NOT (METADATA$ACTION= 'DELETE' AND
> METADATA$ISUPDATE=TRUE)) AS B ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_ID WHEN
> MATCHED   AND b.METADATA$ACTION= 'INSERT'     AND b.METADATA$ISUPDATE
> THEN  UPDATE SET A.EMPLOYEE_ID =B.EMPLOYEE_ID,
> A.SALARY=B.SALARY,
> A.MANAGER_ID=B.MANAGER_ID WHEN MATCHED     AND b.METADATA$ACTION= 'DELETE' THEN DELETE WHEN NOT MATCHED    AND b.
> METADATA$ACTION= 'INSERT' THEN    INSERT INTO
> (EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY,MANAGER_ID)   VALUES
> (B.EMPLOYEE_ID,B.SALARY,B.MANAGER_ID);** Error is: "SQL compilation
> error: syntax error line 15 at position 8 unexpected 'INTO'." Please
> help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little error in syntax here.
Using [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) you don't have to use **INTO** doing an insert on **NOT MATCHED** clause.

So your MERGE query should look like this :

```
MERGE INTO EMPLOYEES_CONSUMER AS A 
USING (
  SELECT * 
  FROM employees_stream 
  WHERE NOT (METADATA$ACTION= 'DELETE' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE=TRUE)
) AS B 
ON A.EMPLOYEE_ID=B.EMPLOYEE_ID 

WHEN MATCHED AND b.METADATA$ACTION= 'INSERT' AND b.METADATA$ISUPDATE THEN UPDATE 
SET A.EMPLOYEE_ID =B.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
    A.SALARY=B.SALARY, 
    A.MANAGER_ID=B.MANAGER_ID 

WHEN MATCHED AND b.METADATA$ACTION= 'DELETE' THEN DELETE 

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND b. METADATA$ACTION= 'INSERT' THEN INSERT (EMPLOYEE_ID,SALARY,MANAGER_ID) VALUES (B.EMPLOYEE_ID,B.SALARY,B.MANAGER_ID)
;
```

Comment: Thank You It's Working now

Comment: @user16595206 you can click the checkmark to mark the answer as accepted if it helps you